# JavaScript Analog Clock

Tags: javascript

I was creating a Analog Clock using javascript for practice and went through a code but I am not able to understand why we need to divide second by 60, min+sec/60 and and hour+min/12 could you please make me understand how this algorithm works? my code is

```
const hour = document.getElementById('hour');
const minute = document.getElementById('minute');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

setInterval(updateClock,1000);

function updateClock() {
let date = new Date()
let sec = date.getSeconds()/60

let min = (date.getMinutes() + sec) / 60;

let hr = (date.getHours() + min) / 12;


hour.style.transform = "rotate(" + (hr * 360) + "deg)";
minute.style.transform ="rotate(" + (min * 360) + "deg)";
second.style.transform = "rotate(" + (sec * 360) + "deg)";
}
updateClock()
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically divide date.getSeconds() by 60 so that you can add it easier to minutes. A better solution would be this:

```js
const hour = document.getElementById('hour');
const minute = document.getElementById('minute');
const second = document.getElementById('second');

setInterval(updateClock);

function updateClock() {
    let date = new Date()
    let sec = date.getSeconds()

    let min = date.getMinutes() + sec/60;

    let hr = date.getHours() + min/60; // you could also add + sec/3600 but that would barely make any difference


    hour.style.transform = `rotate(${hr * 30}deg)`;
    minute.style.transform =`rotate(${min * 6}deg)`;
    second.style.transform = `rotate(${sec * 6}deg)`;
}
```

This gets rid of the bad division that is actually pretty useless as it's only used once.

The multiplication at the end (hr * 30, min*6 and sec*6) are pretty straight-forward. Degrees goes from 0 to 360, but mins and secs only go from 0 to 60. So we multiply them by 6.
Hours go from 0 to 12 so we multiply them by 30.

Also you don't need to call updateClock() at the bottom as it is in the interval.

At the end you should call your interval more often than every second. You can just remove the number so it will be as fast as possible. Or use 100 to make it 1/10th of a second accurate.

Hope I could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have your circle, which has 360 degrees in total. The algorithm you have calculates how much degrees it should turn to show the correct time by dividing the current amount of seconds by the total amount of seconds in a minute. For example.

```
const currentSeconds = 45;
const totalSecondsInMinute = 60;
currentSeconds / totalSecondsInMinute; 
// Result should be 0.75
```

The example here says we currently have `45` seconds, which is 0.75 or 75% of a minute. This number will indicate how much the seconds pointer on the clock must turn in degrees.

```
const secondHandPosition = 360 * 0.75;
// Result should be 270
```

So at `45` seconds the second hand position should be at `270` degrees on the clock. And the same applies to the minute and hour position.